# How to Mock Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path in Pester

Tags: azure-devops, azure-powershell, pester

Need help in Pester!

Script having one function, which calls an inline script using below

```
[string]$ScriptPath = Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

    . $ScriptPath/GetMemberList.ps1 -ErrorAction Stop
```

Pester class context:

```
 Context "xxx returns proper result" {
    BeforeEach {
        
        Mock -Command Split-Path -MockWith { return "C:\xxxx\xxxx\Scripts" }
        $Response = functionxxx @Params
    }
    It "Should return response" {
        , $Response | Should -Not -Be $null
    }
}
```

When I execute Pester, Giving me Below Error;

```
 CommandNotFoundException: The term 'C:\PowerShell\Modules\Pester\5.2.2/GetMemberList.ps1' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
  Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Can someone help me how Can I execute this pester?

Comment: Did you install Pester module? If not please try it `Install-Module -Name Pester -Force -SkipPublisherCheck`

Comment: I have installed. Running other test classes. Used "Install-Module -Name Pester "

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Split-Path Mock isn't working/isn't targeting correctly

When `$script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path` is called in script by pester it returns the Invocation path of pester, not the script. So it is calling `. $ScriptPath/GetMemberList.ps1 -ErrorAction Stop` with `$scriptPath = C:\PowerShell\Modules\Pester\5.2.2`, not the value of `"C:\xxxx\xxxx\Scripts"` you want - and clearly not finding your `GetMemberList.ps1` script as that is not where it lives, hence the error.

If the function `functionxxx` you are testing is from an imported module, then make sure you add the `-ModuleName` flag followed by the the name of the module to the mock call, this should let it target correctly.